# How to fill the <td> with dynamic value on add button click

Tags: javascript, html

**Requirement :**

I want to fill the `td` value with dynamic value after clicking the add button.

**Code**

```
<script>
    function addRow(in_tbl_name)
    {
        var tbody = document.getElementById(in_tbl_name);
        var row = document.createElement("TR");
        var td1 = document.createElement("TD")
        var strHtml1= "<Rule Id>";
        td1.innerHTML = strHtml1.replace(/!count!/g,count);
        var td2 = document.createElement("TD")
        var strHtml2 = "<Rule Name>7;
        td2.innerHTML = strHtml2.replace(/!count!/g,count);
        row.appendChild(td1);
        row.appendChild(td2);
</script>

<td>Selected Plans
    <br>
    <table ID="in_tbl_name" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Rule Id</td>
        <td>Rule Name</td>
    </tr>
</table>


<form action="/SubmitRule" method="post" model="command">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="Select"><c:forEach items="${listRules}" var="rule">
                    <option value="${rule.id}">
                        <c:out value="${rule.id}" />
                    </option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
            </td>           
        <td>
            <input type="submit" onClick="addRow('in_tbl_name')"
            VALUE="AddRow">
        </tr>
    </table>
 </form>
 </td>
```

I am getting the value for an `id` but don't understand how to put that value in `td`.

Comment: Looks like there is a lot wrong with your code. Does this even work when you try it? You are missing closing brackets, quotes and maybe more

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: You are not appending the row to the tbody element anywhere.

Comment: @Rayon Dabre,@ neuhaus i want to display the value in <td> after getting against an id,  that i am failed to do it,and yes its not appended,i dont understand how to append with dynamic value.i want yours help to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code for adding the row in table and also remove the last added row from table

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>

        <script>
            var count=0;
            function addRow(tableId)
            {
                count++;
                var element1=document.getElementById(tableId);
                var tr=document.createElement("tr");
                tr.id="row"+count;

                var td1=document.createElement("td");
                var td2=document.createElement("td");
                var td3=document.createElement("td");

                td1.innerHTML="row"+count+" col 1";
                td2.innerHTML="row"+count+" col 2";
                td3.innerHTML="row"+count+" col 3";

                tr.appendChild(td1);
                tr.appendChild(td2);
                tr.appendChild(td3);

                element1.appendChild(tr);

                alert('row'+count);
            }
            function removeRow(tableId)
            {
                var element1=document.getElementById(tableId);
                var row=document.getElementById('row'+count);
                alert('row'+count);
                element1.removeChild(row);
                count--;
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>


        <a href="javascript:addRow('table')">Add Row</a><a href="javascript:removeRow('table')" >Remove</a>
        <table id="table" border='1'>


        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Actually your current code contains many Javascript and HTML problems**, you need to see more Javascript and HTML courses before diving into it.

Otherwise you need to edit your code and your way to treat the issue too, in order to avoid several problems, for example:

- In your javascript function you don't need to pass the table id as parameter (which you are doing wrong on HTML), you can simply use the id on Javascript without passing it because you are dealing with a single table here.
- Your javascript function is not closed correctly which will fire errors on console(press <kbd>F12</kbd> to see it, it should be closed correctly and in the end of it you are not appendeing the `tbody` to the `table` so the line will never be added.
- And your `HTML` code is incorrect too, for example you are puuting your whole code inside a `<td>` which isn't inside any `<table>` or `<tr>`, you can just use a `<div>` to wrap the whole content.
- In your Javascript code you are missing some quotes `"`, and in your HTML code you are missing some closing tags that should be fixed, and the first `<td>`s for table header can be replaced with `<th>` elements.

---

I tried here to update your code to make it more coherent:

```
<script>
  function addRow() {
      var table = document.getElementById('in_tbl_name');
      var row = document.createElement("TR");
      var td1 = document.createElement("TD")
      var strHtml1 = "<Rule Id>";
      td1.innerHTML = strHtml1.replace(/!count!/g, "count");
      var td2 = document.createElement("TD")
      var strHtml2 = "<Rule Name>";
        td2.innerHTML = strHtml2.replace(/!count!/g,count);
        row.appendChild(td1);
        row.appendChild(td2);
        table.appendChild(row);

    }
</script>

<div>Selected Plans
  <br>
  <table ID="in_tbl_name" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Rule Id</td>
      <td>Rule Name</td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <form action="/SubmitRule" method="post" model="command">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select name="Select">
            <c:forEach items="${listRules}" var="rule">
              <option value="${rule.id}">
                <c:out value="${rule.id}" />
              </option>
            </c:forEach>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="submit" onClick="addRow()" VALUE="AddRow" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

And then you need to focus more on the logic of the code and how to solve your issue of adding new rows.